# create a cart that saves data with localstorage

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, web, local-storage

hi i can't archive data with localstorage.
I am making a shopping cart and I would like that when I change the page or reload the page I do not reset the cart, but the products inside it are kept. how can I do ?
I tried to use the localstorage function but I can't figure out where to put it

my vuejs code,
thanks

```js
 data() {
  return {
    products: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Product 1',
        description: 'This is an incredibly awesome product',
        quantity: 0,
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Product 2',
        description: 'This is an incredibly awesome product',
        quantity: 0,
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Product 3',
        description: 'This is an incredibly awesome product',
        quantity: 0,
      }
    ],
    showCart: false
  };
},

computed: {
  cart() {
    cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.setItem('cart')); 
    return this.products.filter(product => product.quantity > 0);
  },
  totalQuantity() {
    return this.products.reduce(
      (total, product) => total + product.quantity,
      0
    );
  }
},

methods: {
  updateCart(product, updateType) {      
    for (let i = 0; i < this.products.length; i++) {
      if (this.products[i].id === product.id) {
        if (updateType === 'subtract') {
          if (this.products[i].quantity !== 0) {
            this.products[i].quantity--;
            saveCart();
          }
        } else {
          this.products[i].quantity++;
          saveCart();
        }
        break;
      }
    }
  },

  saveCart() {

    localStorage.products = JSON.stringify(products);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `setItem` method to register products in each save you can check [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage#example)

also you need to load localStorage data in `mounted` to retrieve data from `localStrage` if there's any so you can use it

```js
data() {
  return {
    ...
    cartData: [],
    ...
  }
},
mounted() {
  const cartData = localStorage.getItem('cart');
  this.cartData = cartData ? JSON.parse(cartData) : [];
},

methods: {
  saveCart(products) {
    localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(products));
  }
},
```

and then after each `mounted` you can retrieve data inside `cartData` variable

Comment: so I have to change ---- localStorage.products = JSON.stringify (products); ---- in localStorage.setItem ('products') = JSON.stringify (products); and in the mounted I add localStorage.getItem ('products'); right? thank you so much

Comment: it's not `=` is the second parametres of `setItem`, the correct synthax is `setItem(key, value)`

Comment: if i did understand well, you show products based on `quantity` so what you can do is store `products` as is it, and add `this.products = this.cartData` in mounted which will conserve `quantity` updates